# Qt localization: loading the localizable string

Tags: string, qt, localization, qt4, character-encoding

I want to load the localized string in a Qt application. For this, I am following a few steps. Correct me if I am wrong.

Note: it works fine for `QString` but not for `const char*`

1. Update the pro file with
   translation language
2. Generate `.ts` & edit using Qt
   linguist. Generate `.qm` file using
   lupdate and lrelease.
3. Load the .qm file from a particular
   location.

Here is how my `const char*` looks:

```
const char* sayHello =  QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("FriendlyConversation","hello");

LocalizationWithQT::LocalizationWithQT(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
 //ui.setupUi(this);
 QString str = tr("say hello");
 QPushButton *pushbutton = new QPushButton(tr(sayHello));
 setCentralWidget(pushbutton)

}
```

And here's how I am loading the .qm file:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    bool val = translator.load("c:\\Data\\test\\hellotr_la");
    a.installTranslator(&translator);

    LocalizationWithQT w;
    w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
```

The problem is, if I provide any alternate Latin string to "sayhello", it's not loading at all.

I have no idea where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tr(sayHellow)`, Qt will look for the sayHellow translation in the current context (=`LocalizationWithQT` class).

You must give Qt the text context explicitly:

```
QPushButton *pushbutton 
    = new QPushButton(qApp->translate("FriendlyConversation", sayHellow));
```